# How to override an array of dataframes with only one dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am looking for a one liner method to override an array of dataframes with one dataframe,
All i managed to do was :

```
ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> arrayOfDFs...;
arrayOfDFs= null;
arrayOfDFs.add(dataframe);
```

Somebody has a solution?

Comment: The term _override_ means something very specific in Java, and it doesn't seem to match what you intend. Do you mean to _replace_ them? Do those `Dataset`s need to be closed or disposed of before you lose track of them?

Comment: replace all by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can assign a null to your list, and then add something to this list.

You probably need to call arrayOfDFs.clear() ?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_clear.htm

Comment: OK so it's `clear()` then add my element ?

Comment: Yes it's OK to do this.